# Insert without creating duplicates

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-insert

How to load unique data from one table into another table? For example, if I have columns - `patient_id`, `npi`, `diagnosis_code`, `from_date`, `to_date` etc in both tables, how do I make sure a duplicate record is not created in `table 1` when the insert from `table 2` happens.

In PostgreSQL, I can create a unique index on those columns, but Snowflake doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1):

Using INSERT INTO SELECT EXCEPT:

```
INSERT INTO table_1(patient_id, npi, diagnosis_code, from_date, to_date)
SELECT patient_id, npi, diagnosis_code, from_date, to_date
FROM table_2
EXCEPT
SELECT patient_id, npi, diagnosis_code, from_date, to_date
FROM table_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is you can use the [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html) with the `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT` clause:

```
merge into table_1 AS t1 using table_2 AS t2
    ON t1.patient_id = t2.patient_id 
        AND t1.npi= t2.npi 
        AND t1.diagnosis_code= t2.diagnosis_code
        AND t1.from_date= t2.from_date 
        AND t1.to_date = t2.to_date
    when not matched then 
        insert (patient_id, npi, diagnosis_code, from_date, to_date) 
            values (t2.patient_id,  t2.npi, t2.diagnosis_code, t2.from_date, t2.to_date);
```

Comment: How does this compare performance wise with an insert and except? They seem to be pretty similar?

Comment: @YaakovBressler they both should turn into the same hash join logic, so they should be the same speed. But as with most things, I would trying both on the tables you have, and see. And if they are equal I would stick with the one that allows you to read/understand it easiest. I tend to use MERGE's as I like being able to do more with them..

Answer (score 0):

You can try using not exists clause :

```
select
    patient_id,
    npi,
    diagnosis_code,
    from_date,
    to_date
from
    table t1
where
    not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            table t2
        where
            t1.patient_id = t2.patient_id
            and t1.npi = t2.npi
            and t1.diagnosis_code = t2.diagnosis_code
            and t1.from_date = t2.from_date
    );
```